# Android client for OAuth2 with Spring

Tags: android, spring, oauth

anyone can help me to understand how build an Android client for OAuth2 with Spring Framework? I must use Spring for Android or Spring Social or Spring Security? I already have a SaaS build with Spring Framework and it use Spring Security OAuth2 module.

Comment: define `help me to understand` ...

Comment: I don't know where to start.

Comment: by reading the documentation/getting started/readme from the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 is defined in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). The specification does not depend on Spring. So, even if your server-side implementation uses Spring, it does not necessarily mean that your Android application has to use Spring client library. You can use any OAuth 2.0 client library you like. But, it is not so difficult to implement OAuth 2.0 client without any dedicated library.

Probably, the [authorization endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1) of your server for Android applications expect that client applications use "[Authorization Code Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)". If so, what you have to implement is the client-side code of Authorization Code Flow. Loosely speaking, what you need to do is to make a request which is equivalent to the following:

https://your-server.com/your-authorization-endpoint?client_id=your-client-id&response_type=code&scope=space-delimited-list-of-scopes

Your server will return a response whose HTTP status code is "302 Found". The response contains `Location` header whose value is an URL. The query component of the URL contains `code` parameter when the end-user has authorized your client application, or `error` parameter when the end-user has rejected your client application. In either case, you have to extract `code` or `error` from the URL.

The value of `code` is called "*authorization code*". Make a request to the [token endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2) of your server to get an access token.

https://your-server.com/your-token-endpoint?grant_type=authorization_code&code=the-authorization-code-issued-to-your-client-application&client_id=your-client-id

Read [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and then ask for your friends or colleagues for more details.